# Can I assign a keyboard shortcut to Compiz "window overview" effect

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, compiz

I recently enabled Compiz 3D effects in my CentOS. I am getting this awesome "Window Overview" effect when I move my mouse to the top right corner of the screen. Just wondering if I can have a keyboard shortcut for the same effect.

Instead of moving the mouse to the top right corner, I want to have a keyboard shortcut that gives me the "Window Overview" effect[showing all open/maximized windows].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

open ccsm
choose option "scale"
change to tab "bindings", here you can set Edge bindings, keyb-bindings and mouse-bindings

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I think I should have been more specific in my question. I am looking for the command to bind to the keyb bindings.